# Any historical work on the distribution of prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, gauss, primes

I am looking to see whether historic mathematicians did any work to explain the slightly unexpected distribution of prime gaps?

I would have expected Gauss, who studied lists of primes and proposed a form for their average density $1/\log(n)$, to have considered this question too?

The following chart plots the log of prime gap counts for each gap in the number range 1 to 500 million. It is unusual to see such a linear and tightly bounded shape.

[image]

I believe, but am not certain, that no results have been proven to explain the shape of this distribution.

Comment: Gauss did not look into prime gaps, but I am guessing that this shape is reproduced by [Cramer's random model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture). There are also oscillations in the graph related to divisibility by 6 that can be accounted for by known corrections to it.

Comment: Some google-fu leads me to [this paper](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0887-10.pdf), which could be a starting point for a more extensive search.